# Unity and Firebase Transaction Thread Trapped

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing with Firebase and Unity. I've experienced a problem with Threads freezing. The problem does not occur when running in unity editor, only when running on Android device.

I have a scene with a button. On Button press a firebase transaction occurs , and the scene is changed. I have used Android Monitor to investigate and I receive a dump with lines such as : "IdleHandler threw exception from firebase", "other thread is trapped; signum = 11", "main thread is trapped"

below is an example of the code that is run on a button press in GUI.

It seems to be related to this issue on github: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/181

```
public void on buttonPress()
{

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.LogLevel = Firebase.LogLevel.Debug;
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                //transaction code
                return TransactionResult.Success(data);
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            }
        });


        // firebase code is running, now change scene 
        SceneManager.LoadScene("blah");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the SceneManager.LoadScene("blah"); up

```
public void on buttonPress()
{

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.LogLevel = Firebase.LogLevel.Debug;
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            console.log('before if'); //log something here
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                //transaction code
                console.log('true')
                return TransactionResult.Success(data);
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            }
            // firebase code is running, now change scene 
            SceneManager.LoadScene("blah");
        });
}
```

This means the next scene won't load till the async finished and the task is called

Comment: Hi - I just implemented this solution but the Scene does not change now . Regards.

Comment: This might mean that the call back is not called or that something in the code fails. To see what is happening I added some logs above, what do you get?

Comment: Change to `ContinueWithOnMainThread`, since you may be trying to load the scene on another thread.

The method is available after adding `using Firebase.Extensions;`